# Inconsistent behaviour with proc greplay in batch vs. interactive sessions

Tags: pdf, graph, sas

I have some SAS code that draws 2 charts on identically scaled axes - one stacked vertical bar chart, and one line chart. It then draws the lines on top of the bars via proc greplay to produce a stacked bar + line chart. This is output to pdf via ODS.

When I run my code in an interactive SAS session, it works as intended - the 2 charts are the same size and line up exactly on top of one another. However, if I run exactly the same code in a batch session, the bar chart is squashed into the left half of the chart area and the line chart is displayed at full size.

Any idea what could be causing this? It's possible that there are some different settings between the batch and interactive sessions, but I'm not sure which ones could be responsible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was only including the final proc greplay inside the ODS sandwich used to produce the pdf. Once I put the preceding chart procs, goptions statements etc. there as well (using goptions nodisplay to make sure that the individual charts didn't end up in the PDF before being overlaid), it all rendered as expected.

Comment: I would guess the GOPTIONS are the more important part of that, the procs themselves shouldn't matter unless you are relying on the graphs to be named/numbered in a particular order, which you should be able to deal with without requiring you to have the procs run.